# Docker needs to install software that uses a wizard

Tags: docker

Fairly new to Docker but I got it all setup pretty nicely. I due still have a question about some software I need to install.
This software has an installer where the user needs to provide input to the install script. How can Docker handle this? I have to press enter a few times or accept the default values.

Comment: The software doesn't accept an answer file? That's kind of unusual.

Comment: A little detail about the installer would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

if you run docker with the arguments `-i` to connect stdin, and `-t` to create a pseudo-tty, then that might solve your problem?